# Worried about my Buddha hand rind ferment

Tags: fermentation, citrus

I am testing out the Buddha hand fruit ferment.
I washed everything well, cut the rind and poured honey water in the jar and sealed it tight. I opened it one day and it bubbled for a few minutes very strongly. I put the top back on and now there is a white film on top of the liquid and I am not sure what or if something went wrong.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, you shouldn't seal anything fermenting because it could accumulate too much pressure and fail in a potentially explosive manner (as with this unfortunate accident https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/glass-carboy-explosion.517237/).

Also, white films forming on top of fermenting beverages usually means that an infection got hold (and the fermentation vessel, if not made of glass, usually will harbor these bugs from now on and infect the next batches). A good ressource here : https://www.homebrewsupply.com/learn/is-my-batch-infected.html

It's not uncommon in fruit based fermentation if everything isn't frozen then pasterized. Regarding if it's drinkable, it would need a proper identification of the bugs you got in there, but folks over at https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit to answer this kind of question. Stay safe!